# Cmake: cannot open output file no such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am learning to use cmake for a project using a shared library, but I keep getting this error:

```
Linking CXX executable test/test/robot_test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file test/test/robot_test: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test/test/robot_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test/robot_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project("Particle Filter")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
include_directories(include)

set(LIB_SOURCES src/robot.cc src/sampler.cc src/general.cc)
set(LIB_HEADERS include/robot.h include/sampler.h include/general.h)

add_library(my_lib SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES} ${LIB_HEADERS})
install(TARGETS my_lib DESTINATION lib)

set(APP_SOURCES test/robot_test.cc test/sampler_test.cc)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test")

foreach(test ${APP_SOURCES})
    #cut off .cc of src files using empty string
    string(REPLACE ".cc" "" testname ${test})
    add_executable(${testname} ${test})
    target_link_libraries(${testname} my_lib)
endforeach(test ${APP_SOURCES})

add_definitions(
    -std=c++11 # Or -std=c++0x
    # Other flags
)
```

Here is my tree (excluding the build directory that contains a lot of this such as my makefile,.so and .a file):

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── driver.cc
├── include
│   ├── general.h
│   ├── robot.h
│   └── sampler.h
├── lib
├── notes
├── src
│   ├── general.cc
│   ├── robot.cc
│   └── sampler.cc
└── test
    ├── robot_test.cc
    └── sampler_test.cc
```

Also, the .so or .a files are not getting saved to my lib folder after sudo make install, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter for command [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html) is not a *filename* but a name of **target**. Target's name shouldn't contain special symbols like slash ("/").

You may control output directory of executables created by setting variable [CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html):

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test")
...
# Relative path to executable will be 'test/robot_test'.
add_executable(robot_test robot_test.cc)
```

Comment: It gives me new error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file test/test/robot_test: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test/test/robot_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test/robot_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Edit your question and show how you modify the code.

Comment: I updated it. It made an empty "test" folder in my build folder.

Comment: You still use `test/robot_test` as **target** name. It should be `robot_test`.

Comment: As both your sources are located in the same directory, you may store in variable `APP_SOURCES` their names without directory: `robot_test.cc sampler_test.cc`. Creating executable will be changed to `add_executable(${testname} test/${test})`. More complex way is to process each path to file with [get_filename_component](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/get_filename_component.html) and assign directory component to the *property* [RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) of created target.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also fixed it by adding "string(REPLACE "test/" "" testname ${test}) ". But yours work better.